# How to serialize type boost::labeled_graph

Tags: c++, serialization, boost-graph

I've got a boost:labeled_graph object type which does not seem to have necessary functions for serialization.

```
    error: ‘class boost::labeled_graph<boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::listS,
 boost::undirectedS, Space, spaceEdge, graphProperties, boost::listS>, std::basic_string<char,
 std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::defaultS>’ has no member named
 ‘serialize’
```

Any way of serializing labeled_graphs to file?

Comment: At first you can check whether labeled_graph really doesn't have such a function in boost source. Then you can try more recent version of boost. It can have such a function. If not you should make it yourself. The quick and dirty way is to separate labeled graph into two parts: usual boost graph and container of additional info which is special for labeled graph. Then you can create this two data structures from your labeled graph and serialize them in standard way. I don't know differences between labeled_graph and adjacency_list. So there may be a simpler and faster way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not seen before, but [`labeled_graph` looks like a thin wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/graph/labeled_graph.hpp) around another graph of your choosing, in this case you chose `adjacency_list` by the looks of that error. There's boost support for serializing adjacency lists via `<graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>`, so it looks like you can use the [free function serializing](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/serialization.html#free) quite sensibly with this, something like:

```
template<class Archive>
inline void serialize(
    Archive & ar, 
    my_grap_typedef & g, 
    const unsigned int /*file_version*/
){
  ar & g.graph()
}
```